Парсинг котировок с Binance winforms
Добрый день всем кто читает это!
Написал парсер котировок с binance с помощью chatgpt. Он мне выдает такую строку:

Я думаю что можно как-то извлекать из этой информации именно цену и помещать ее в вещественную переменную, но не совсем понимаю как.
Еще есть функии:
        ConnectSocketBtcUsdt();
        ConnectSocketEthUsdt();

Для парсинга btcusdt и ethusdt соответственно. Не совсем понимаю как они работают, поэтому не совсем понимаю как их можно объединить в одну, чтобы можно было парсить много котировок.
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using WebSocketSharp;

namespace WinFormsBinanceApiSocketTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private WebSocket ws;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Load += Form1_Load1;
        }

        private void Form1_Load1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectSocketBtcUsdt();
            ConnectSocketEthUsdt();
        }

        void ConnectSocketBtcUsdt()
        {
            // Initialize WebSocket connection
            ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/btcusdt@trade"); // Change symbol as needed
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Handle incoming message
                HandleMessageBtcUsdt(e.Data);
            };
            ws.Connect(); // Connect to the WebSocket server
        }


        void ConnectSocketEthUsdt()
        {
            // Initialize WebSocket connection
            ws = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/ethusdt@trade"); // Change symbol as needed
            ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Handle incoming message
                HandleMessageEthUsdt(e.Data);
            };
            ws.Connect(); // Connect to the WebSocket server
        }

        private void HandleMessageBtcUsdt(string message)
        {
            label1.Text = message;
        }

        private void HandleMessageEthUsdt(string message)
        {
            label2.Text = message;
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Close WebSocket connection when the form is closing
            ws.Close();
        }

    }
}

Еще как правильно вставлять пример кода на c# в вопрос?
Заранее спасибо всем, кто заинтресовался.
Следуя совету  EvgeniyZ, задал уточняющий вопрос ChatGPT

Он мне помог разобраться с тем как извлеч из этой информации котировку в числовом формате.
С тем как создать универсальный метод для любых котировок, есть идея осталось только реализовать.
А вот в том как правильно вставлять C# код в вопрос, пока не уверен. Может тоже у ChatGPT спросить?.. :) И о том как смайлы вставлять :)

Чтож вы дальше свою GPT не спросили? А вообще, завязывайте с ней, не советую новичку вообще ей пользоваться, только убьете желание разбираться, изучать, что-то делать, ну и получите ужасный код (например, посмотрите сколько раз вы открываете и сколько раз закрываете соккет). Ну а так, читайте то, что по ссылке выше.

Открываете 2 вебсокета, а закрываете один. Странно.

aepot, не совсем понимаю. По-моему сокет один ws открывается в двух методах для разных валютных пар. Или я ошибаюсь?..
